# ASP.NET accordion and calendar makes button click event not raise

Tags: asp.net, calendar, onclick, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I have this accordion with 3 panes. On one of these panes there is a button which is supposed to raise a click event but it does not. I have tried to remove all validators which didn't work, to remove CalendarExtenders which didn't work, to put the button outside the accordion which didn't work, to comment out the accordion with the button outside which didn't work, to comment out the calendar which didn't work, but when I comment out both the calendar and the accordion it triggers the event properly. I check if it fires by placing a breakpoint in the proper method and the request is also timed out when it doesn't work.

The markup is as following:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="calendar">
        <asp:calendar id="Calendar1" runat="server" backcolor="#6dc066" bordercolor="#000000" borderwidth="2px" font-names="Verdana" font-size="1.2em" forecolor="White" height="400px" width="400px" style="margin-right: 0px" cellpadding="4" daynameformat="Shortest" ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender" onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged">
            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="9pt" />
            <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#000000" />
            <TitleStyle BackColor="#494949" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFFF" ForeColor="Black" />
            <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#487346"/>
        </asp:calendar>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-div">
        <asp:Accordion ID="MyAccordion" runat="Server" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordion" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="true" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true">
            <Panes>
                <asp:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="InfoPane">
                    <header>Informationer om valgt dato</header>
                    <Content>
                        <div style="margin: 5px;">
                            <b>Startdato: </b><asp:Label runat="server" ID="startLabel" />
                            <br />
                            <b>Slutdato: </b><asp:Label runat="server" ID="endLabel" />
                            <br />
                            <b>Reserveret af: </b><asp:Label runat="server" ID="authorLabel" />
                            <br />
                            <b>Kommentarer: </b><asp:Label runat="server" ID="commentsLabel" />
                            <br />
                            <b>Reserveringstidspunkt: </b><asp:Label runat="server" ID="bookedTimeLabel" />
                        </div>
                    </Content>
                </asp:AccordionPane>
                <asp:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="BookingPane">
                    <Header>Reservering</Header>
                    <Content>
                        <div style="margin-left: 10px; width: 350px;">
                            <h3>Reserver:</h3>
                            <p>
                                <b>Startdato: </b><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStart" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="right-align"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:CalendarExtender FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" ID="txtStart_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtStart" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="StartRequired" ControlToValidate="txtStart" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Udfyldelse er påkrævet" Display="Dynamic"/>
                                <asp:RangeValidator ID="StartRange" ControlToValidate="txtStart" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Startdato skal være efter i dag" Type="Date" Display="Dynamic"/>
                                <br />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <b>Slutdato: </b><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEnd" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="right-align"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:CalendarExtender FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" ID="txtEnd_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtEnd" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EndRequired" ControlToValidate="txtEnd" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Udfyldelse er påkrævet" Display="Dynamic"/>
                                <asp:RangeValidator ID="EndRange" ControlToValidate="txtEnd" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Slutdato skal være efter i dag" Type="Date" Display="Dynamic"/>
                                <br />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <b>Kommentar: </b><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComment" CssClass="right-align"></asp:TextBox>  
                                <br />
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="customVal" ControlToValidate="txtEnd" ErrorMessage="En af de valgte dag er booket" OnServerValidate="customVal_ServerValidate" Display="Dynamic"/>
                                <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStart" ErrorMessage="Startdatoen skal være før slutdatoen" ControlToCompare="txtEnd" Operator="LessThanEqual" Type="Date" Display="Dynamic"/>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Button ID="BookButton" runat="server" OnClick="BookButton_Click" Text="Reserver" BackColor="LightGray" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black"/>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="SuccesLabel" Visible="false" BackColor="LightGreen"/>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </Content>
                </asp:AccordionPane>
                <asp:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="MyReservationPane">
                    <header>Mine reservationer</header>
                </asp:AccordionPane>
            </Panes>
        </asp:Accordion>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tested your code. It reveals that you are getting date format mismatch. As you set the date format to British in calendar extenders, but the custom validators evaluating against American date format. Hence, stopping you from post back on button click. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code. It reveals that you are getting date format mismatch. As you set the date format to British in calendar extenders, but the range validators evaluating against American date format. Hence, stopping you from post back on button click.

If this is the case, you may add following in your Page_Load (code behind):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: yaar ali, apna skype tou dou naa yaar